# Open-Source software to open Adobe LiveCycle Designer Template File

Tags: adobe, livecycle

Does any open-source (or reasonably priced) software exist to enable me to open and edit an Adobe LiveCycle Designer template file (.TDS extension)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what "reasonably priced" mean. Livecycle Designer can be bought for circa 300 Euro, so compared to LiveCycle ES (or even Photoshop) it is not very much.

For small changes you can use text editor (like Notepad++), because .tds files are just ordinary xml files.